# Polishing up the VBA & Json Format

Tags: json, vba

We are almost getting the write Json format with VBA all we need now another hand to assist in polishing it up.

(1) The parameter is working fine
(2) All the products are now coming

Issues

(1) A set of products is repeating 3 times when deburg. print , want to show only once!

(2) The Json header with dates together with the outside transaction object will cause the json not to accepted by the machine/gadget RS 232. The rest is correct , that is what is required!

```
Private Sub CmdSales_Click()

'  Const SQL_SELECT As String = "SELECT * FROM Qry3;"

  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim fld As DAO.Field
  Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
  Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
  Dim root As Dictionary
    Set root = New Dictionary

    Dim transaction As Dictionary
    Dim transactions As Collection
    Dim item As Dictionary
    Dim items As Collection
    Dim invoice As Dictionary
    Dim invoices As Collection

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Set transactions = New Collection
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Qry4")
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm = Eval(prm.Name)
Next prm
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset()

Set qdf = Nothing
 rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Set transaction = New Dictionary
        transaction.Add "PosSerialNumber", DLookup("PosSerialNumber", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv)
        transaction.Add "IssueTime", DLookup("IssueTime", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv)
        transaction.Add "Customer", DLookup("CustomerName", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv)
        transaction.Add "TransactionTyp", 0
        transaction.Add "PaymentMode", 0
        transaction.Add "SaleType", 0

        '--- loop over all the items
        Dim itemCount As Long
        itemCount = 3
        Set items = New Collection
        For i = 1 To itemCount
            Set item = New Dictionary
            item.Add "ItemID", i
            item.Add "Description", DLookup("Description", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            item.Add "BarCode", DLookup("BarCode", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            item.Add "Quantity", DLookup("Qty", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            item.Add "UnitPrice", DLookup("unitPrice", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            item.Add "Discount", DLookup("Discount", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))

            '--- loop over all the invoices
            Dim invoiceCount As Long
            invoiceCount = 1
            Set invoices = New Collection
            For j = 1 To invoiceCount
                Set invoice = New Dictionary
                invoice.Add "Total", DLookup("TotalAmount", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
                invoice.Add "IsTaxInclusive", DLookup("Inclusive", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
                invoice.Add "RRP", DLookup("RRP", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
                invoices.Add invoice
            Next j
            item.Add "Taxable", invoices
            items.Add item
        Next i
        transaction.Add "Items", items
        transactions.Add transaction
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    root.Add "JSON Created", Now()
    root.Add "Transactions", transactions

    Dim json As String
    json = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(root, Whitespace:=3)
    Debug.Print json

End Sub
```

Current results:

```
{
   "JSON Created": "2019-10-10",
   "Transactions": [
      {
         "PosSerialNumber": "102010",
         "IssueTime": "2019-09-15",
         "Customer": "J J Zingalume",
         "TransactionTyp": 0,
         "PaymentMode": 0,
         "SaleType": 0,
         "Items": [
            {
               "ItemID": 1,
               "Description": "Apple (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227328",
               "Quantity": 15,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 615,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "ItemID": 2,
               "Description": "Orange (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227329",
               "Quantity": 11,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 451,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "ItemID": 3,
               "Description": "Water (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227337",
               "Quantity": 12,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 492,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "PosSerialNumber": "102010",
         "IssueTime": "2019-09-15",
         "Customer": "J J Zingalume",
         "TransactionTyp": 0,
         "PaymentMode": 0,
         "SaleType": 0,
         "Items": [
            {
               "ItemID": 1,
               "Description": "Apple (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227328",
               "Quantity": 15,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 615,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "ItemID": 2,
               "Description": "Orange (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227329",
               "Quantity": 11,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 451,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "ItemID": 3,
               "Description": "Water (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227337",
               "Quantity": 12,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 492,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "PosSerialNumber": "102010",
         "IssueTime": "2019-09-15",
         "Customer": "J J Zingalume",
         "TransactionTyp": 0,
         "PaymentMode": 0,
         "SaleType": 0,
         "Items": [
            {
               "ItemID": 1,
               "Description": "Apple (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227328",
               "Quantity": 15,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 615,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "ItemID": 2,
               "Description": "Orange (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227329",
               "Quantity": 11,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 451,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "ItemID": 3,
               "Description": "Water (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227337",
               "Quantity": 12,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 492,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

(1) The products should only show once NOT 3 times

(2) The header Json date & object transactions ARE NOT required

"JSON Created": "2019-10-10",
   "Transactions": [

Comment: The `itemCount = 3` statement was only in the code to set a limit. The example code has no way of knowing or understanding how many items there really are or where to get the item list. So you'll have to change where you're getting the items from. Currently, you're getting it from the userform. If you keep it that way, then you'll only have one item in your items list.

Comment: It also looks like you may not need the outer loop at all (the one that loops over all the records in the recordset). That's where you're getting the three repeats of the same product. Your post yesterday indicated that you wanted to loop over the recordset to do "something". If all you want is to get the one product from the userform, then remove the outer loop.

Comment: I'm not getting my items from the subform all my items are coming from QRY4 as a record source

Comment: The only help I need is to have the invoice header from  "PosSerialNumber": "102010","IssueTime": "2019-09-15","Customer": "J J Zingalume","TransactionTyp": 0,"PaymentMode":"SaleType": 0,"Items":  to be be in objects , now what is happening , both the Arrays and the objects are are housed under transactions collection that is where the problem is here.

Comment: Please do not post duplicates. Please complete your other questions before asking new questions

Comment: In fact I see a consistent history of you asking questions, getting an answer, then requesting more assistance then just leaving it open and asking a new question. Please don't use this site in this way. Please close your existing questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Peter T

I followed your comments carefully and also I removed the following:

(1) Invoices collection was incorrectly linked I replaced that with the tax collection and linked it to items dictionary and finally to transaction now I have a proper Json!

Regards

Chris